# MLPerf Benchmark : Can MLPerf benchmark a system without GPU / a system setup with only CPU?

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, cpu, benchmarking, cpu-usage

MLPerf is well known to benchmark a GPU system for ML capability.
As VMs with GPU are expensive and someone wants to run any ML task on a CPU-only system. Is it possible to benchmark a CPU-only system via MLPerf?